# VOD server performance test

Tags: streaming, video-streaming, ubuntu-12.04, load-testing, rtsp

I have two VOD servers (RTSP) each on a different machine in a local network at home (vlc and Darwin streaming server).

What i am trying to do is a performance test that goes as follows:
    * send in 10 requests, 50, then 100.
    * redo the same but request multiple files instead of emulating multiple access to a single file.
    * output statistics (speed, quality...etc).
What i have right now is OpenRstp which uses "-Q" to output Qos info but it is nowhere near what i need.

What i need is a free tool that can help me with this...all the ones i found (divesifeye and IxLoad) are not free.

Could anyone please suggest something useful?

Comment: Try flazr or https://artillery.io/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a method that should do. It is based on openRTSP with "-Q" for Qos statistics.
the trick is how to redirect the data to a file as the Qos info only shows up after the feed is cut off. i wrote the following script to manage N-readings of a video feed/playlist. It will create a file that will contain the Qos info.

```
    #!/bin/bash
f_rtsp(){
clear
echo -e "ENTER THE NUMBER OF STREAM USERS:"
echo -n "USER:"
read usr
for((i=1; i <= $usr;i++))
do 
exec &> /$HOME/Desktop/results
echo -e "******************************* $i *****************************"
openRTSP -Q rtsp://<url>/<playlist-name>.sdp &
done
}
while : #Loop forever
do
cat <<!
Benchmark.RTSP

1.RTSP consumers
2.EXIT
!
echo -n "YOUR CHOICHE? :"
read choice

case $choice in 
1|[rR]) f_rtsp ;;
2|[eE]) exit ;;

*) echo "\"$choice\"is not valid"; sleep 2 ;;
esac
done
```